# gitignore rule to always include folders with a specific name

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a root .gitignore file (Visual Studio) in my project root folder. In some subfolder's I have a folder named 3rdParty which contains folders like lib, debug and release with dll files in it.

[image]

I want to commit these to my GIT repo.

In my .gitignore on rootlevel the debug and release are excluded.

```
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
```

I have tried putting a .gitignore file in the several 3rdParty folders without the debug and release rule.

```
#[Dd]ebug/
#[Dd]ebugPublic/
#[Rr]elease/
#[Rr]eleases/
```

But that didn't work. Is there a way I can set a ! rule in my root .gitignore so that all folders named 3rdParty on all levels are included?

Comment: can you screenshot your directory structure

Comment: I have added an example. But the location of the folder 3rdParty  is variable. So I would like to have a rule that works no matter were the folder is located in the folder structure

Comment: In the documentation I read: A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere. But that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule !**/3rdParty/** does the trick after all. I had the rule above:

```
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
```

When I placed the rule at the bottom of my .gitignore it works. I got the rule from:
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

In this section:

> Two consecutive asterisks ("`**`") in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:
>
> A leading "`**`" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "`**/foo`" matches file or directory "`foo`" anywhere, the same as pattern "`foo`". "`**/foo/bar`" matches file or directory "`bar`" anywhere that is directly under directory "`foo"`.